# Keeping CentOS up to date in a flexible way without giving out root credentials?

Tags: rhel, yum, upgrade

Title was "Running `yum update && yum upgrade` without root-privileges?"

I want to allow an unprivileged user to start a system update on a RHEL-based system (CentOS 7). `yum-cron` is not an alternative, because the user should be flexible e.g. he should be able to decide when to shutdown the machine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply setup your `sudoers` file and allow a user or a group to execute this one specific command. Syntax would look somehow like this in file `/etc/sudoers` (edit with `visudo`!):

```
user    ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/yum update root
```

If you omit the `NOPASSWD` part, the user will have to provide *his* password. The users will get to run this simply as `sudo yum update`.

For more information, you can consult manual pages for [`sudoers(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers)

Comment: Thanks, already thought about a sudo solution. Are you sure about the 'obsolete alias' aspect? In my understanding it sets the `--obsoletes` flag and is not obsolete in itself.

Comment: yes, you are right. I read and wrote too fast. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is no, it is not possible without root priviledges.

Deeper answer is you could compromise your system by making a sudo user user without a password. Which I don't recommend.

Comment: What about manually executing yum-cron. Is that possible?

Comment: I will rephrase my question.